# Using Monolog WebProcessor with Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, monolog

I see that new logging stack/channels provides a way to `tap` or define `handlers`. However, I'm trying to get `WebProcessor` loaded and it doesn't seem to work. Should this be tapped? Or is there a different way to load this?

This is specific to Laravel 5.6. Here is what I used in my older application that uses Laravel 5.2 (`bootstrap/app.php`):

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function (Monolog\Logger $monolog) {
    /* Include basic http props in logs */
    $webProcessor = new Monolog\Processor\WebProcessor();
    $monolog->pushProcessor($webProcessor);
});
```

@AkenRoberts I tried `tap => Monolog\Processor\WebProcessor::class` which I guess is not right.

Comment: What have you tried? What does "doesn't seem to work" mean - are there errors? Show us some of your 5.6 code.

Comment: @AkenRoberts I tried `tap => Monolog\Processor\WebProcessor::class` which I guess is not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. After a bit of research it seems like `tap` is the best way to hook `processors`. So, if I want to tag a processor to all the handlers in the current logging stack I could do be by add this:

```
tap => [App\Logging\MyClass::class]
```

This class in turn will push required processors onto all the handlers within it's `__invoke` method.

```php
namespace App\Logging;
use Illuminate\Log\Logger;

class MyClass {
    /**
     * Customize the given logger instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Log\Logger  $logger
     * @return void
     */
    public function __invoke(Logger $logger)
    {
        foreach ($logger->getHandlers() as $handler) {
            $handler->pushProcessor(new WebProcessor);
        }
    }
}
```