# Laravel 5.6. How to push Monolog processor

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-5.6, monolog

This issue is somewhat a "more broad version" of

[Using Monolog WebProcessor with Laravel 5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51677615/using-monolog-webprocessor-with-laravel-5-6)

I need to add Monolog Processor (which one is not so important for now) to my stack in Laravel.

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has solved the issue.

```
class PushUidProcessor
{
    /**
     * Pushed uid processor for adding a unique identifier into records.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Log\Logger $logger
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __invoke(Logger $logger)
    {
        collect($logger->getHandlers())->each(function ($handler) {
            $handler->pushProcessor(new UidProcessor);
        });
    }
}
```